# Samsung GT-S7392 is locked because of attempting password too many times. Please help me out

Tags: password, locked-out

Samsung GT-S7392 is locked because of successive password attempts; and I could not access or log into the google account as well. The question is: Can I l get unlock through theses using my google account where I'm not the first user of the device. It also asks me for the back up pin. What actually is it and how do I solve 'unlock' this? Please help me.

Comment: Well, you can try unlocking your device with the Google Account if that account is what the device is using ! Other than that there isn't any option !

Answer (score 2):

*On a side note: This is very suspicious.*

**Anyway**, regarding this question:

> The question is: Can I l get unlock through theses using my google account where I'm not the first user of the device.

You can only unlock the device using **one of the Google accounts associated with the phone**. If you don't know the password or any of the phone's account credentials, then you're out of luck.

For the next question:

> It also asks me for the back up pin. What actually is it and how do I solve 'unlock' this?

**There is no universal backup PIN**. You can only unlock the phone with the  PIN/password that was set or the credentials of an associated Google account.

Alternatively, you wipe the `/data` directory on the device to perform a factory reset, which will also reset the password.

## **Warning: Performing a *factory reset* will delete all user data.**

Answer (score -1):

You can restore the phone. Find and download the firmware for the phone. Go checkout www.xdadevelopers.com or google the phones firmware. You'll need to download Odin. You will also need to download the bootloader and the modem besides the firmware. If you want to do this. Let me know. Ill give you step by step directions.

**DOING THIS METHOD WILL DELETE EVERYTHING FROM THE PHONE, FRESH START.**

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts.  This is a question-and-answer site, as opposed to a forum.  We encourage answers that are complete, so if you can include step-by-step directions, it would be most helpful.